# view not updated while changing class variable value angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a component which has a variable myName

```
export class ConversationComponent implements OnInit {
  private myName: string;

  showNames(name)
  {
    this.myName=name;
  }
}
```

the value is set by using `showNames()`,and it is displayed by

```
 <h4>{{MyName}} </h4>
```

but when the value is set to the variable the change is not reflected in the view ie html page.

Here's my Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { ConversationComponent } from './conversation/conversation.component'; 

@Injectable() export class ChatingService { 

  constructor(private Conversation:ConversationComponent) { } 

  setValue(val) { 
    this.Conversation.showNames(this.myValue); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Create plunker which generate the issue you have mentioned.

Comment: Where do you call `showNames(...)`?

Comment: it call from a service..

Comment: import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ConversationComponent } from './conversation/conversation.component';
@Injectable()
export   class ChatingService {

 constructor(private Conversation:ConversationComponent) {
  
     }
 setValue(val) { 
    
     this.Conversation.showNames(this.myValue);
    
   }
}

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there. Code in comments is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Injecting a component into a service doesn't work. You need a different approach. You probably injected a component class instance that is not related in any way to the component shown on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Component(...)
export class ConversationComponent implements OnInit {
  private myName: string;

  constructor(private service:ServiceClass) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showNames(this.service.getName());
  }

  showNames(name) {
    this.myName=name;
  }
}
```

Here `ServiceClass` is your injectable `Service`.

Comment: in my project on load there will not be any value in the variable the value is set on button click in another component in my page,so i cant use ngOnInit()

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/sasxa/e1164d9773b31459f6dc) is the gist which demonstrate communication between sibling components via service. You can consider it. But if your components are nested then it will be better to communicate using events and callback between parent and child.